# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean' - Spring config problems

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm trying to set up Hibernate 4 with Spring 4, and I have run into some problems configuring it.  Specifically, in my `servlet-context.xml` file, I followed a guide and added the following code blocks to this file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Both of these display the following error: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'`

The session factory bean also displays this error: `Cannot locate BeanDefintionParser for element [bean]`

Here is my entire `servlet-context.xml' file (excluding those two code blocks for brevity's sake, though please notice that they are actually in the file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <!--  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />-->
    <!--   <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> -->
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="pear.pear.pear" />

</beans:beans>
```

How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of adding the namespace prefix: `beans:bean`?

Comment: It was..how silly!  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You set the default namespace for that XML file to `mvc`, so you'll need to prefix your element (`beans:bean`) or change the default namespace to `beans` (the usual approach).